# Add a Different CSS Class Into The Body Tag of Different WP Pages

Tags: php, pages, css

I'm transferring a 20 page static HTML site to a custom Wordpress Theme. On each page of the static site the `body` tag has a custom CSS class i.e. 'banking-page'.

I know that WP generates page id classes in the body tag to represent the individual pages (i.e. .page-id-27), but in terms of readability (and transferability), is it possible to add a bit of php onto each page which will insert a specific class into the body tag CSS for that particular page? Using the `body_class()` function won't do it because it will show on every page.

Thanks in advance

Emily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your functions.php:

```
function my_body_class($classes) {

    if(is_page()){
      global $page;
      $title = get_the_title(  $page );
      $classes[] = $title;

    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'my_body_class');
```

That will add the page title as a class to each page.

Comment: this code throws an error on the `classes[] = $title` line.

Comment: I forgot the $ on classes.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of options for you.

**Option 1: Use the `body_class()` function to add the page slug to the class.**

```
function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
     global $post;
  if ( isset( $post ) ) {
     $classes[] = $post->post_name;
  }
  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );
```

Then whatever the url is, say "yourdomainpage.com/banking-page" then it'll grab "banking-page" as a class for the body. This does mean your urls needs to line up with your classes, so that may not be the ideal solution.

**Option 2: Add a body class meta box to your pages.** I prefer using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for this, but it can also be done using the [add_meta_box()function](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/).

Once you've got that filled in, you use the same function as listed in option 1, except you replace `$post->post_name;` with your meta box / [ACF field value](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

Answer (score 0):

You want to add different CSS class on different page. 
You can do it by checking it by page or page id. It's going to bit long work for you. However, you can do it two way. (May be more ways are there but I suggest you these two)

For both you should have added following code into active theme's header file where you render body tag

> `<body <?php body_class( 'class-name' ); ?>>`

1. Check the page using code in the body_class filter(Hook):

   ```
   add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 1);
   function add_custom_class( $classes ) {
       if ( is_page( 57 ) ) { 
           // 57 is your desire page id for example
           // if ( is_page ( 'home' ) ) { // the slug of page
           array_merge( $classes, array( 'home-class' ) );
       } elseif( is_page( 58 ) ) { 
           // elseif ( is_page('about-us') ) {
           array_merge( $classes, array( 'about-class' ) );
       } elseif ( is_page( 60 ) ) { 
           // elseif( is_page('contact-us') )
           array_merge( $classes, array( 'contact-class' ) );
       } 
       // until all your pages are finished.
       return $classes;
   }
   ```
2. Another way is add meta box or custom field on each page in wp-admin and add class of that page and modify above code as follow:

```
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 1);
    function add_custom_class( $classes ) {
        // If you're using custom-field or meta that should be shaved in postmeta table
        global $post;
        $page_class = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_key', true );
        // You can use Advance custom field plugins to add fields into your posts/pages
        // If you use ACF plugin you can use get_field( 'selector', $post->ID ) instead of get_post_meta(...);
        if ( is_page() ) {
            if( '' != $page_class ) {
                array_merge( $classes, array( $page_class ) );
            }
        } 
        return $classes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// add body class for that.
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        $classes[] = 'article-page';
    }

    else{
      if(!is_page('library'))  $classes[] = 'home';
    }
    if(is_page('contact-page')){
       $classes[] = 'contact-page';
    }   
    if(is_page('banking-page')){
      $classes[] = 'banking-page';
    }
  return $classes;
}
```